# Angular-formly, template options key "horizontal"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, angular-formly

Code example:

```
 _.each(allFields, function(field) {
            _.deepDefaults(field, {
                templateOptions: {
                    horizontal: 5
                }
            });
        });
```

What is mean at key "horizontal" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this key in template.
Example:

```
<div ng-class="::to.horizontal ? to.horizontal : ''">
```